# Cannot append text to File

Tags: java, android

My code is :

```
if(myfile.exists()) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myfile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =  new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (LatLng item : markerArrayList) {
            myOutWriter.append(item.toString());
        }
        myOutWriter.append("\n\n");
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }        
}
```

When I use `myOutWriter.append`, what really happens is that every time I'm writing to the file, it overwrites previous content.

Comment: There isn't : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you do not use the append option of the [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) constructor.

You should use:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myfile, true);
```

instead, to open the file for appending.

Otherwise, it overwrites the contents of the previous file.

Answer (score 2):

use FileOutputStream's secondconstructor :

`FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)`

with append value as  `true`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the cursor that is marking the place where the `OutputStreamWriter` is starting to write into the file is at the very beginning of the file.

What you want to do is to set it to the end of the file using the alternative constructor of [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29%20FileOutputStream%20(Java%20Platform%20SE%207)) that has a boolean attribute. The fixed code would be:

```
if(myfile.exists()) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myfile, true);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =  new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        for (LatLng item : markerArrayList) {
            myOutWriter.append(item.toString());
        }
        myOutWriter.append("\n\n");
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```